# Table detection using tesseract api

Tags: c#, ocr, tesseract

Is there any way using tesseract ocr detect tables.

I am using the following c# code (charlesw/tesseract)

```
using (var iter = page.GetIterator())
{
    iter.Begin();
    do
    {
        var blockType = iter.BlockType; // Never equals to Table

    } while (iter.Next(PageIteratorLevel.Word));
}
```

Iterating over blocks and querying `BlockType` property, but it never returns `PolyBlockType.Table` value, even if I had table in my document

I have also tried to set "textord_tabfind_find_tables" variable to true, but no luck.

Comment: Have you tried changing Page Segmentation Mode? Which mode is it set right now? https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/wiki/ImproveQuality#page-segmentation-method

Answer (score 0):

I've only been able to find tables with PSM 1, 2, 3, 4; this was a key for me.

I've not been able find tables in all my docs, so I crafted one in a Google Doc (with some other text) and two tables, and exported as PDF, then converted to PNG with 300 and 600 dpi.  It's able to find my full-width table, but not my half-width table.

With tesserocr Python bindings:

```
ret = api.SetVariable('textord_tabfind_find_tables', 'true')  # 400: 1
ret = api.SetVariable('textord_tablefind_recognize_tables', 'true') # 400: 0
ret = api.SetVariable('textord_tablefind_show_mark', 'true')  # 400: 0
ret = api.SetVariable('textord_tablefind_show_stats', 'true')   # 400: 0

if args.scrollview:
    api.SetVariable("textord_show_tables", "true")  # launches ScrollView

api.Recognize()
level = RIL.BLOCK           # BLOCK, PARA, SYMBOL, TEXTLINE, WORD
riter = api.GetIterator()
for r in iterate_level(riter, level):
    if args.tablesonly is False or PT_NAME[r.BlockType()] == 'TABLE':
        print('### blocktype={}={} confidence={} txt:\n{}'.format(
            r.BlockType(), PT_NAME[r.BlockType()],
            int(r.Confidence(level)), r.GetUTF8Text(level)))
```